# Oracle Row Access Statistics

Tags: oracle

Here is a problem i am trying to solve -

Scenario:

1. Oracle production database having a table with large number of rows(~700 million)
2. Accumulated over the period,say 10 years

Requirement:

Partition it, in such a way that one partition should have rows which are being accessed or updated over a "period of defined time" and another will have rows which are never retrieved or updated in that "defined period of time".

Now since this table has updated timestamp columns it is easy to find out rows that are updated.

So i want to know is there any in-built row level stats available which can give me this info about row access?

Comment: Not unless you happen to have been doing fine-grained auditing of `select` statements throughout the period of defined time.  That said, the requirement does not make sense.  It's not a business requirement-- a business requirement does not specify a technical implementation.  It does not seem to make sense as a technical requirement.  Technically, you might want to partition a table to separate frequently accessed data from infrequently accessed data but there is no reason to care whether a row is never accessed or seldom accessed.

Answer (score 0):

SCN could help, if you want to find row modification time.

```
   Select scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn), t.* from my_table t;
```

Note: scn highly depends on table definition - i.e. it could be defined as row level or block level. Another thing, there is a limit to which the oracle save the scn to timestamp mappings.